# Encoding IPIPIP Frames from x264 baseline 420 profile

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, x264, libx264, video-codecs

I am new to FFMPEG. I am trying encode a stream in alternate I-Frames and P-Frames for the baseline profile IPIPIPIPIP.

I searched FFMPEG forums but was not able to get the required output

My script file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:./FFMPEGEncLibs
./ffmpegEnc -f rawvideo -r 25 -s 176x144 -vcodec rawvideo -i ./encIn/akiyo_qcif.yuv -c:v libx264 -x264-params cabac=0:8x8dct=0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 4.1 -psnr -intra -qp 9 -vframes 10 ./encOut/akiyo_cif.h264
```

Can someone suggest me changes to my script file, so that i would be able to encode in stream in IPIPIP format

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you use a GOP of len 2 and turn off b-frames, I don't know what else it could do...

Comment: of course you could still end up with IPIPIPIIIPIPI on a scene change

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i file -x264opts keyint=2:min-keyint=2 outfile
```

will add a new keyframe every second frame. The other frame will be a P frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed my script file as below ./ffmpegEnc -f rawvideo -r 25 -s 176x144 -i ./encIn/akiyo_qcif.yuv -x264opts keyint=2:min-keyint=2 -c:v libx264 -intra -qp 30 -vframes 3 ./encOut/akiyo_cif.h264                                                                                    When i remove this -intra flag, I getting a error. If i keep this my second frame will also be I-Frame itself. Can u suggest me should i keep this flag or remove it.

Comment: @CodecGuy You should show the actual error. A link to a pastebin, or an update to your question showing the complete console output would be helpful.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, here is the output of my console
[codecguy@platinum TestVectors]$ sh scripts.sh
  libavutil      52. 46.101 / 52. 46.101
  libavcodec     55. 36.100 / 55. 36.100
  libavformat    55. 19.102 / 55. 19.102
  libavdevice    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 88.101 /  3. 88.101
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[rawvideo @ 0x1660ce0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from './encIn/akiyo_qcif.yuv':

Comment: Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 176x144, 7603 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 176x144, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
hcount : 10 , vconut : 8
ERRORO HOW DID THIS COME INTO I_8x8[codecguy@platinum TestVectors]$

Comment: @CodecGuy That's not the complete console output, and I was hoping you would avoid trying to cram this info into comments. As I mentioned earlier, use a link to a pastebin service, or even better, edit your question with the updated info.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Here is the link to my paste bin http://pastebin.com/b8y7zZ4E
If i remove -intra flag, I am getting this Error